# Converting Query String into Array in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, query-string, windows-store-apps

Given that you cannot use name-value pairs in a Windows Store app, what is the appropriate namespace for doing same? I want to convert the following querystring `?param1=value1&param2=value2`

How can I shape this to:

`Arrayname[param1]=value1`

`Arrayname[param2]=value2`

Comment: Take a look at [`WwwFormUrlDecoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.wwwformurldecoder).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the Dictionary<key,value> class?

Comment: By Array, I believe sure OP meant Dictionary<string,string>

Answer (score 0):

Create this method to parse the string.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetDelimitedValues(string candidateString,
                                                         char pairDelimeter,
                                                         char valueDelimiter)
    {
      var nameValueStrings = candidateString.Split(new char[] { pairDelimeter },
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      var splitPairs = nameValueStrings.Select(item =>
                                               item.Split(new char[] { valueDelimiter },
                                                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

      var keyValuePairs = splitPairs.Select(x =>
                                             new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x[0],
                                              x.Length > 1 ? x[1] : string.Empty));

      return keyValuePairs.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    }
```

Call the method like the following example.

```
  string urlEnd = "?param1=value1&param2=value2&color=blue&size=m";
  urlEnd = urlEnd.TrimStart('?');

  var results = GetDelimitedValues(urlEnd, '&', '=');

  // get an item from dictionary
  var colorString = results["color"];
  var sizeString = results["size"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also disappointed that Windows Store apps (Metro C# apps) don't have access to System.Web which contains HttpUtility.ParseQueryString().

Thanks to Romoku's suggestion above, I was able to convert a query string to a Dictionary using WwwFormUrlDecoder:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2");
WwwFormUrlDecoder decoder = new WwwFormUrlDecoder(uri.Query);
Dictionary<string,string> queryParams = decoder.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This probably won't do what you expect if you have a query string that has two parameters with the same name but different values (e.g. `param1=value1&param1=value2`)